# Computing the genus in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

That's an exercise but I'm not so sure how to approach this. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $f(t)$ be a polynomial in $k[t]$ of degree $d$. Let $C$ be the curve that corresponds to the field extension $k(x,t)$ of $k(t)$, where $x^p + x = f(t)$. Suppose that $C$ is smooth. The problem is then to find the genus of $C$.

The idea is of course to use Hurwitz' theorem but I'm not sure how to rule out wild ramifications. I am also generally interested in how to approach this kind of question (look at valuations, look at the equations in projective space, etc)

Comment: It seems likely that you won't be able to "rule out" wild ramification ... because depending on the degree $d$ there will be cases where you do have wild ramification. I remember doing this problem a few years ago and found it fun and enlightening. I'll play around with it later today to see if I remember how it goes.

Comment: The interesting case is, when $\gcd(d,p)=1$. Otherwise you can reduce the degree of $f$ by a substitution (assuming that $k$ is perfect). Over the infinite place of $k(t)$ you are bound to have wild ramification. IIRC with the gcd condition in place you get $g=(p-1)(d-1)/2$. There is an accessible derivation of the Hurwitz formula of any Artin-Schreier extension in [Stichtenoth's book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-76877-7). This field extension is cyclic of degree $p$, so you should be able to determine the higher ramification groups, and use Hilbert's formula.